# unable to run commands in shell script after su mqm command,but able to run in putty?Pleae let me know how to execute.?

Tags: bash, queue, ibm-mq

My script is,

```
#!/bin/bash

su mqm
echo "DISPLAY QLOCAL (<QUEUENAME>) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc QUEUEMANAGER
```

---

same command works in putty but not through script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putty is interactive command line. Try the below. bash variables can be used.

```
#!/bin/bash
su - mqm -c "echo 'DISPLAY QLOCAL (<QUEUENAME>) CURDEPTH'|runmqsc QUEUEMANAGER"
```

Comment: Thanks nsupathy..I am able to get queue details through script.

Answer (score 1):

"su mqm" is not the same as "su - mqm".

From the man page for su

> -, -l, --login
>
> ```
> make the shell a login shell
> ```

Therefore, you need to dash "-" to pickup mqm's profile.

When in doubt, type man su (or whatever command) for more information.